# How to save and retrive Pandas dataframes with hierarchichal indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, save

I need to created and save a Pandas dataframe with hierarchical indexing. In the following I create two dataframes, and then concatenate them to create a new dataframe with hierarchical index.

```
data1 = np.random.rand(5,5)
data2 = np.random.rand(5,5)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],  index=['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],  index=['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['first', 'second'])

print "Original Data frame"
print df

# Save to file.
df.to_csv('test')

# Read from file.
df_new = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('test')

print "Saved Data frame"
print df_new
```

Here is output that I get,

```
Original Data frame
                  a         b         c         d         e
first  i1  0.926553  0.180306  0.182887  0.783061  0.832914
       i2  0.899054  0.130367  0.615534  0.965580  0.669495
       i3  0.931004  0.425528  0.068938  0.166522  0.714399
       i4  0.082365  0.587194  0.993864  0.187864  0.066035
       i5  0.668671  0.294744  0.136317  0.358732  0.529674
second i1  0.916310  0.361423  0.700380  0.386119  0.273667
       i2  0.102542  0.454106  0.565760  0.259323  0.104743
       i3  0.410280  0.379986  0.288921  0.177819  0.919343
       i4  0.447279  0.113711  0.032273  0.335358  0.717824
       i5  0.995781  0.356817  0.146785  0.972401  0.169360

Saved Data frame
       Unnamed: 1         a         b         c         d         e
first          i1  0.926553  0.180306  0.182887  0.783061  0.832914
first          i2  0.899054  0.130367  0.615534  0.965580  0.669495
first          i3  0.931004  0.425528  0.068938  0.166522  0.714399
first          i4  0.082365  0.587194  0.993864  0.187864  0.066035
first          i5  0.668671  0.294744  0.136317  0.358732  0.529674
second         i1  0.916310  0.361423  0.700380  0.386119  0.273667
second         i2  0.102542  0.454106  0.565760  0.259323  0.104743
second         i3  0.410280  0.379986  0.288921  0.177819  0.919343
second         i4  0.447279  0.113711  0.032273  0.335358  0.717824
second         i5  0.995781  0.356817  0.146785  0.972401  0.169360
```

When I save this new dataframe to a csv file ('test') and read it back, I loose the hierarchical indexing. Is there a way to save the data into a file, such that when I read it back, I retain the hierarchical indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save it in another way than using csv. For instance pickle:

```
df.to_pickle('dataframe.pickle')
```

This preserves the hierarchical index. You read it again doing:

```
pd.read_pickle('dataframe.pickle')
```

Pandas has several IO methods, you can read about them in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can:

Reset the index and save the DataFrame to csv, read it back from csv, and then
 set the index back to the original (inplace).

```
df
Out[11]: 
                  a         b         c         d         e
first  i1  0.935478  0.455757  0.607418  0.850291  0.704326
       i2  0.675752  0.339017  0.999949  0.508480  0.888817
       i3  0.463371  0.803389  0.048469  0.599697  0.423603
       i4  0.935294  0.933699  0.843289  0.182535  0.255847
       i5  0.321236  0.120010  0.647876  0.000517  0.032592
second i1  0.172044  0.691660  0.799164  0.194785  0.302880
       i2  0.432988  0.511229  0.451268  0.203145  0.560563
       i3  0.442584  0.771483  0.839945  0.716374  0.533183
       i4  0.167898  0.962646  0.152245  0.400280  0.210355
       i5  0.736365  0.511057  0.256672  0.619250  0.790739

df.reset_index()
Out[12]: 
  level_0 level_1         a         b         c         d         e
0   first      i1  0.935478  0.455757  0.607418  0.850291  0.704326
1   first      i2  0.675752  0.339017  0.999949  0.508480  0.888817
2   first      i3  0.463371  0.803389  0.048469  0.599697  0.423603
3   first      i4  0.935294  0.933699  0.843289  0.182535  0.255847
4   first      i5  0.321236  0.120010  0.647876  0.000517  0.032592
5  second      i1  0.172044  0.691660  0.799164  0.194785  0.302880
6  second      i2  0.432988  0.511229  0.451268  0.203145  0.560563
7  second      i3  0.442584  0.771483  0.839945  0.716374  0.533183
8  second      i4  0.167898  0.962646  0.152245  0.400280  0.210355
9  second      i5  0.736365  0.511057  0.256672  0.619250  0.790739

df.reset_index().to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df3 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df3.set_index(['level_0', 'level_1'], inplace=True)

>>> df3
Out[15]: 
                        a         b         c         d         e
level_0 level_1                                                  
first   i1       0.935478  0.455757  0.607418  0.850291  0.704326
        i2       0.675752  0.339017  0.999949  0.508480  0.888817
        i3       0.463371  0.803389  0.048469  0.599697  0.423603
        i4       0.935294  0.933699  0.843289  0.182535  0.255847
        i5       0.321236  0.120010  0.647876  0.000517  0.032592
second  i1       0.172044  0.691660  0.799164  0.194785  0.302880
        i2       0.432988  0.511229  0.451268  0.203145  0.560563
        i3       0.442584  0.771483  0.839945  0.716374  0.533183
        i4       0.167898  0.962646  0.152245  0.400280  0.210355
        i5       0.736365  0.511057  0.256672  0.619250  0.790739
```